# is there a way to specify class unextendable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

as we use "final" keyword to declare a class non-extendable in java. How do we achieve this in ruby? is there any way?

Comment: Java's `extends` and Ruby's `extend` are very different. To avoid confusion, it might be better to rephrase your question using language-independent terms.

Comment: If you wish to prevent a class from having a subclass, you should use similar words in stating the question, without reference to Java. The relationship with Java is irrelevant. Moreover, at present the question can only be answered by readers familiar with both languages, which is unnecessarily restrictive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want to prevent subclassing, you could `raise` an exception from within the [`inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-i-inherited) callback:

```
class Foo
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    raise "Can't inherit Foo class"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo ; end
#=> RuntimeError (Can't inherit Foo class)
```

Comment: +1, short and sweet. I would `raise` something more specific, such as a `TypeError` or a custom subclass `UninheritableError < TypeError` instead, though.

Comment: Note that this will not prevent subclassing. Subclassing is already a done thing by the time `.inherited` is triggered. If the exception is caught, you can go on as if nothing happened. However, Ruby has always assumed one was an adult about these things - the mere existence of `.send` means that there can be no access control, just access... suggestion.

Comment: It could be undone though... I'm thinking `subclass.name.split('::').tap { |*m, c| m.inject(Object) { |a, m| a.const_get(m) }.send(:remove_const, c) }` before the `raise` might do it. (There might be an easier way to write this, but I couldn't think of one)

Comment: @Amadan that would merely remove the constant, not the subclass itself. Besides, if someone knowingly ignores that exception, who am I to stop them? ;-)

Comment: The constant is the only reference to that subclass. Even if you have something like `class Bar < Foo; Quux = self; end`, the `.inherited` happens as soon as `class Bar < Foo` is executed; so `raise` would prevent the `Quux` assignment. If you delete the (AFAIK single) reference to the class, it's a) useless and not really reachable, and 2) eventually gets GC'd. E.g. (at least in my env) `GC.start; ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < Foo }` will not find it any more - so I'd argue it does remove the subclass itself. However, I agree that this is a very un-Rubyish concern :)